Age Rest Bank IMF code
What is the International Monetary Fund Code for Age Rest Bank? I require it in order to complete a transaction

Judging from the age of its web site (very new) and lack of mention elsewhere, it doesn't appear to me be a legitimate bank. It is very likely a scam. I recommend you do not transact.

There's no such thing as "International Monetary Fund Code". This is a scam. Googling the "Age Rest Bank", there's probably no such bank either. The website looks like a typical scam front, mentioning an address in Poland that according to Google is a home improvement store while showing a map pointing at a Walmart in Massachusetts .

Agerest.com was only registered this February, for a one-year lease. If that's the domain you've been dealing with, this further suggests they are not legitimate. I think you can assume that any money you have given them is gone, and any fees you pay now will vanish along with it.
Research companies before doing business with them.
https://www.whois.com/whois/agerest.com reports:
Registered On: 2024-02-23
Expires On 2025-02-23 
Updated On 2024-02-23 
Status: clientTransferProhibited 
Name Servers: ns1.dns-parking.com,
              ns2.dns-parking.com 
Registrant Contact Country: NL 
Email: https://mydomainprovider.com/contact_domain/

